# TCPDF Text overlaps image

Tags: php, html, css, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to generate a pdf out of HTML. In the code, there is an image with a `span` below it. Unfortunately, my `span` is overlapping my `img`.

I know it's better to set the `span` as a `figure`, but since TCPDF doesn't support html5, I thought this was the best way to solve it.

The code looks something like this:

```
<img src="">
<span>Some text related to the image</span>
```

So the output will print a image with a text on the bottom of the picture. Is there any way I can get the text below of the picture?

Comment: Open your browsers console and inspect the image / text, then click on the image code (in the console) to see the CSS applied to this image, fiddle around with it until the text is below the image, without knowing how or what css is all ready applied it's hard for us to suggest anything, but look into the "display" property, try set it do `display:block;` if it's not all ready.

Comment: Nope, I've still got the same. Just a quick reminder this happends when I output the HTML into the PDF, not on the webpage itselve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [HTML2PDF](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default), instead of TCPDF? The syntax is mostly identical, and the amount of supported CSS is much greater. You could use margin-top or padding-top to distance the span further from the image.